# Python loop (insert items in a list at dermined places)

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
number = 2
size = 5
list_b = [("b","b","b")]
list_a = [("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a")]
for i in range(number):
   list_a.insert(size,list_b)
print list_a
```

it gives me this:

```
[('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('b', 'b', 'b'),
('b', 'b', 'b'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a')]
```

basically, it inserts 2 times the `list_b` in the position defined by `size`

I want a loop that repeats itself so that `list_b` is inserted the number of times defined in `number` but repeats `size` times. It difficult to explain, so here is the result that I want:

```
[('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'), 
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'), 
('a', 'a', 'a'), 
('b', 'b', 'b'), 
('b', 'b', 'b'), 
('a', 'a', 'a'), 
('a', 'a', 'a'), 
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('b', 'b', 'b'),
('b', 'b', 'b'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'), 
('a', 'a', 'a'), 
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('b', 'b', 'b'),
('b', 'b', 'b'), 
('a', 'a', 'a'), 
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('b', 'b', 'b'),
('b', 'b', 'b'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'a', 'a'),
('b', 'b', 'b'),
('b', 'b', 'b'),...and so on]
```

**EDIT**

and if I had this:

```
 list_a = [a, ] * 15
 list_b = [b,]
 s = 5
 n = 2
```

I want to obtain this:

```
 [b,b,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,a,a,a,a,a,b,b]
```

since this is an example and list_a, s and n will vary, how can I do this in one or two loops?

Thanks,

Favolas

Comment: Please use the pprint output--this is kind of hard to read.

Comment: @Ignacio I tried but didn't found a solution. Probably I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @Favolas replace `print list_a` with `import pprint; pprint.pprint(list_a)`

Comment: @Favolas: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqfOxm_1BE0

Comment: number and size are almost always terrible variable names unless they're member variables. Indicate what the variable actually is with its name, aka size of what?

Comment: @Crazy... its just an example. Not using that names

Comment: What's the point in using so long list for the example?

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of the argument, I'll call the `('a', 'a', 'a') => a` and `('b', 'b', 'b') => b`.

```
number=2
size=5
list_a=["a"]*20
list_b=["b"]

workfor=len(list_a)+(len(list_a)/size)*number*len(list_b)
i=0
while i<workfor:
    i+=size
    for times in range(number):
        for elem in list_b:
            list_a.insert(i,elem)
        i+=len(list_b)

print list_a
```

Results in =>

```
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

number = 2
size = 5
list_b = [("b","b","b")]
list_a = [("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a"),("a","a","a")]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    insertion_count = len(list_a) / size
    for j in xrange(insertion_count):
        # compute insertion position
        pos = (j+1)*size + j * number
        for i in range(number):
            list_a.insert(pos,list_b)
    print list_a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain, izip, repeat

list_a = [('a', 'a', 'a')] * 15
list_b = [('b', 'b', 'b')]

a5b2s = [iter(list_a)] * 5 + [repeat(*list_b)] * 2
list_a[:] = chain.from_iterable(izip(*a5b2s))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't use any modules. Just basic programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s,n=5,2
>>> a=[1,]*17
>>> b=2
>>> for i in range(len(a)//s*s,0,-s):
    for j in range(n):
        a.insert(i,b)

>>> a
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Whenever you insert a new item to a, the len(a) of a increases. You forgot to take that in consideration.

Comment: Hi there. This works but i don't understand. In this case, range(len(a)//s*s,0,-s) will be the same as range(0,0,-5) so the range goes from 0 to 0 in a -5 jump?? That doesn't make sense to me. I've edited my initial post so see if you can help-me. Thanks